# Empty List from JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm having some trouble fetching data from the PiHole API;

This is the JSON format (from the url http://pi.hole/admin/api.php?summary):

```
{
  "domains_being_blocked": "1,089,374",
  "dns_queries_today": "34,769",
  "ads_blocked_today": "11,258",
  "ads_percentage_today": "32.4",
  "unique_domains": "9,407",
  "queries_forwarded": "17,972",
  "queries_cached": "5,539",
  "clients_ever_seen": "35",
  "unique_clients": "23",
  "dns_queries_all_types": "34,769",
  "reply_NODATA": "1,252",
  "reply_NXDOMAIN": "625",
  "reply_CNAME": "10,907",
  "reply_IP": "21,004",
  "privacy_level": "0",
  "status": "enabled",
  "gravity_last_updated": {
    "file_exists": true,
    "absolute": 1588474361,
    "relative": {
      "days": "0",
      "hours": "14",
      "minutes": "18"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct NetworkController {
    static func fetchData(completion: @escaping (([PiHole.Stat]) -> Void)) {
       if let url = URL(string: "http://pi.hole/admin/api.php?summary") {
          URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
                let stat = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PiHole.self, from: data)
                completion(stat?.stats ?? [])
            }
          }.resume()
       }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [PiHole.Stat] = []

    func fetchData() {
        NetworkController.fetchData { messages in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.messages = messages
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.messages, id: \.self) { stat in
                Text(stat.domains_being_blocked)
            }
        }.onAppear{
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

Data.swift

```
struct PiHole: Decodable {
    var stats: [Stat]

    struct Stat: Decodable, Hashable {
        var domains_being_blocked: String
        var ads_percentage_today: String
        var ads_blocked_today: String
        var dns_queries_today: String
    }
}
```

Everything seems okay, no errors, yet when I run it, the simulator only shows an empty list

In Playground I can retrieve those data just fine:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PiHoleTest: Codable {
    let domains_being_blocked: String
    let ads_blocked_today: String
}

let data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string: "http://pi.hole/admin/api.php?summary")!)

do {
    let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder.init()
    let user: PiHoleTest = try decoder.decode(PiHoleTest.self, from: data)

    print("In Blocklist \(user.domains_being_blocked)")
    print("Blocked Today: \(user.ads_blocked_today) ")


} catch let e {
    print(e)
}
```

The Output:

```
In Blocklist 1,089,374
Blocked Today: 11,258
```

What am I doing wrong? Or better, is there another way to fetch these stats?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Never `try?`, catch the `error` and print it. At first view you can see that the JSON contains neither a key `stats` nor any array.

Comment: Yeah, there's no, `stats` key in the JSON itself, but it's coming from the `Data.swift` where `stats` is the whole `Stats` array... Isn't it? 
Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the whole thing... (Pretty new to SwiftUI)

I see the JSON is not an array, that's what I'm struggling with the last two days, seems like that with an array it would've been much simpler (at least looking at all the tutorials online on how to deal with JSONs), but this is what I'm getting from the API...

Is there a way to parse that kind of JSON format and get back the data?

Comment: You have to create your data structs according to the JSON, not vice versa, *it's coming from the JSON*. Build the struct based on `PiHoleTest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the structure. Your JSON decoded were not an array. So PiHole struct was unnecessary. I can tested and this code is working now.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NetworkController {
    static func fetchData(completion: @escaping ((Stat) -> Void)) {
        if let url = URL(string: "http://pi.hole/admin/api.php?summary") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let data = data {
                        let stat = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stat.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            completion(stat)
                        }
                        return
                    } else {
                        print("Error Found")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stat: Stat? = nil
    func fetchData() {
        NetworkController.fetchData { stat in
            self.stat = stat
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(viewModel.stat?.domains_being_blocked ?? "No Data")
            Text(viewModel.stat?.ads_blocked_today ?? "No Data")
            Text(viewModel.stat?.ads_percentage_today ?? "No Data")
            Text(viewModel.stat?.dns_queries_today ?? "No Data")
        }.onAppear{
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

struct Stat: Decodable, Hashable {
    var domains_being_blocked: String
    var ads_percentage_today: String
    var ads_blocked_today: String
    var dns_queries_today: String
}
```